# Add Textbox values in CheckedListBox( as items) using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

i'm using vb.net to make a UI that connects via RS232. the 1st output that i defined is some kinda list of products, that i defined to be showed in a textbox.

Now i need to add items to that checkedlistbox. Don't mind the full list , think as it was only 1 product .
Example, textbox1.text="apple", so i want add the item "apple" to the listbox.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SerialPort1.Write("Products" & vbCr)
    Dim separated = TextBox1.Text.Split(";")
    CheckedListBox1.Items = separated.Text        'i know this is wrong :('       
End Sub
```

i tried everything , but there's no similar question anywhere. and pls, tell me what i've done wrong in the post before downvote ! cumps

Comment: Please describe your expected behavior and the actual misbehavior of your code. Are the items empty? null? other error?

Comment: Items is a readonly property.  You need to use Items.AddRange.

Comment: Expected-> textbox1.text="apple", so i want add the item "apple" to the checkedlistbox. At this point it does nothing.. 
@Aaron , i've tried already. done! :) ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items is readonly.  You need to use Add or AddRange.  Since you're creating an array already, change it to this.

```
Dim separated = TextBox1.Text.Split(";")
CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange(separated)
```

Comment: You will probably run into adding duplicate items if you click more than once without changing the text.  I'll edit the answer for a fix

Comment: that's not a problem for me. my worst problem is not having each "split" for each row.